# how to use non-static method generics?

Tags: java

I want to get sql by following code :

```
public class Mappers {
    public static class SqlBuilder {
       //SqlImpl class implements Sql, and select,from,method,alias,where return this. 
       public static <T> SqlImpl<T> builder() {
         return new SqlImpl<>();
       }
    }
}
```

Define the relationship

```
    public interface Join<T> {
      //select * from tab_a a left join tab_b b on a.col1 = b.col2
      Join<T> leftJoin(Sql<T> Sql); 
      //select * from tab_a a left join tab_b b `on a.col1 = b.col2`
      // 1.Function implements Serializable 
      // 2.class.getDeclaredMethod("writeReplace") 
      // 3.get field name
      <T1,T2> Sql<T> on(Function<T1,Object> bf1,Function<T2,Object> bf2)
    }
```

Sql interface

```
 public interface Sql<T> extends Join<T> {
        // select a,b,c ...
        Sql<T> select(BuilderFunction<T, Object>... t);
        // from tab_a,tab_b 
        Sql<T> from(Class<T> t); 
        // select * from tab_a a
        Sql<T> alias(String name); 
        //select * from tab_a where col = ?
        Sql<T> where(SqlCondition condition); 
        // get sql 
        String build(); 
    }
```

I want to use function like:

```
Mappers.SqlBuilder.<A>builder()
                             .select(A::getAId,A::getName)
                             .from(A.class)
                             .where(new SqlCondition().andEquals(A::getName,"x"))
                             .leftJoin(Mappers.SqlBuilder.<B>builder()
                                                             .select(B::getAId,B::getBId)
                                                             .from(B.class)
                                                             .alias("b_tab")
                              )
                              .on(A::getAId,B::getAId); // error: Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`.
```

A and B

```
@Table(name="a_tab")
class A {
  private Long aId;
  private String name;
//getter setter
}

@Table(name="b_tab")
class B {
  private Long bId;
  private Long aId;
//getter setter
}
```

1. My problem is with the method `on`, I can't use on(`A::getAId,B::getAId`), I get `error: Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`.
2. I can't understand  `Function<A,Long> af = A::getAId;`  different `A::getAId`

Comment: Please add code for class A and B.

Comment: "non-static method generic assignment" is not a question, is it? Please, make sure the subject/heading is written as a proper sentence giving the context of what you need, ideally in the form of a proper question.

Comment: Do you know about [MyBatis](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/)? It looks to me like you are trying to do the same thing.

Comment: `A::getAId` is indeed a static method reference, i.e. it refers to static method `getAId()` of class `A`. Of-course method `getAId()` is not static. Hence you need an instance of class `A` first, e.g. `A a = new A()`. Then you can use `a::getAId()` rather than `A::getAId()`.

Comment: SqlImpl instance hava some field to build sql, so i can't use static method.

Comment: @Abra Yes, I want to expand MyBatis query.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Modify `Join<T> leftJoin(Sql<T> Sql);` to `Join<T> leftJoin(Sql Sql);`, full source code:

```java
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.function.Function;

interface Join<T> {
    //select * from tab_a a left join tab_b b on a.col1 = b.col2
    Join<T> leftJoin(Sql Sql);
    //select * from tab_a a left join tab_b b `on a.col1 = b.col2`
    // 1.Function implements Serializable
    // 2.class.getDeclaredMethod("writeReplace")
    // 3.get field name
    <T1,T2> Sql<T> on(Function<T1,Object> bf1, Function<T2,Object> bf2);
}

interface BuilderFunction<T,R> {
    R build(T t);
}

class SqlCondition {

    public <T> SqlCondition andEquals(BuilderFunction<T, String> f, String x) {
        return this;
    }
}

interface Sql<T> extends Join<T> {
    // select a,b,c ...
    Sql<T> select(BuilderFunction<T, Object>... t);
    // from tab_a,tab_b
    Sql<T> from(Class<T> t);
    // select * from tab_a a
    Sql<T> alias(String name);
    //select * from tab_a where col = ?
    Sql<T> where(SqlCondition condition);
    // get sql
    String build();
}

class SqlImpl<T> implements Sql<T> {

    @Override
    public Join<T> leftJoin(Sql Sql) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <T1, T2> Sql<T> on(Function<T1, Object> bf1, Function<T2, Object> bf2) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Sql<T> select(BuilderFunction<T, Object>... t) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Sql<T> from(Class<T> t) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Sql<T> alias(String name) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Sql<T> where(SqlCondition condition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String build() {
        return null;
    }
}

@Table(name="a_tab")
class A {
    private Long aId;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Long getAId() {
        return aId;
    }

    //getter setter
}

@Table(name="b_tab")
class B {
    private Long bId;
    private Long aId;

    public Long getAId() {
        return aId;
    }

    public Long getBId() {
        return bId;
    }

    //getter setter
}

public class Mappers {
    public static class SqlBuilder {
        //SqlImpl class implements Sql, and select,from,method,alias,where return this.
        public static <T> SqlImpl<T> builder() {
            return new SqlImpl<>();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mappers.SqlBuilder.<A>builder()
                .select(A::getAId,A::getName)
                .from(A.class)
                .where(new SqlCondition().andEquals(A::getName,"x"))
                .leftJoin(Mappers.SqlBuilder.<B>builder()
                        .select(B::getAId,B::getBId)
                        .from(B.class)
                        .alias("b_tab")
                )
                .on(A::getAId,B::getAId); // error: Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u,I get the sql ,but why? What BuilderFunction.build method mean.I  don't really understand  lambda :: .

Comment: Because with ```Join<T> leftJoin(Sql<T> Sql);``` then ```Mappers.SqlBuilder.<A>builder()```, T = A, so if you want to call 'leftJoin' you must pass ```Sql<A>```, but in your case, you're passing: ```Mappers.SqlBuilder.<B>builder()```, Sql<A> != Sql<B>, so you get the error

Comment: 'What BuilderFunction.build method mean', because you didn't post 'BuilderFunction' class's content, so I must fake that class, :)

Comment: @VGR,I change  `Join<T> leftJoin(Sql sql) `to `<T1 extends Sql> Mappers.Join<T> leftJoin(T1 sql)`,.